# node js Master Slave replication with read and write queries split up

Tags: node.js, postgresql, load-balancing, master-slave, pg-promise

My application runs on node js and using PostgreSQL(pg-promise) for the database connection. I want that all write queries should go to master instances of DB and read queries to slave instance. I have set up the server configuration prostgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf files. 
Now,how will the application will get to know that read queries going to slave and write to the master. Is there any library we have to install.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is pgpool-II - http://www.pgpool.net/mediawiki/index.php/Main_Page

It is a multi-purpose tool, it can not only replicate your master db to slave DBs but will do load balancing for you. You have to just connect to your pgpool server, it will balance your write/read queries accordingly.